# Запуск майнкрафт (forge 1.7.10) из-под своего лаунчера

Tags: java, minecraft, launcher

Кратко и по делу. Нужно запустить майнкрафт из-под своего лаунчера. Пишу на java. Перерыл весь интернет в поисках того, как это сделать. Ничего не нашёл. Нашёл лишь способ 10-и летней давности. Как вы уже догадлись - он не работает. Может кто-нибуть знает, как запустить minecraft forge 1.7.10 из-под своего лаунчера на java?

Пробовал способ запуска через java applet. Не вышло.
В кратце:
Парсю файл json, где хранятся все нужные библиотеки и пути к ним.
Каждый путь к файлу записываю как ссылку и помещаю её в массив ссылок.
Затем весь массив загружаю urlclassloader-ом.
Затем пытаюсь запустить класс launchwrapper, а там выдаёт ошибку

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.mainlauncher.MCLauncher (in module com.mainlauncher) cannot access a member of class net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch with modifiers "private"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:385)
```

**Вызов класса launchwrapper**

```
public void init(int i){
        URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls); // В массиве urls есть все нужные библиотеки для запуска.
        System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", bin + "natives");
        System.setProperty("net.java.games.input.librarypath", bin + "natives");
        System.setProperty("fml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates", "true");
        System.setProperty("fml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies", "true");
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", bin + "natives");

        try{
            Class <?> Mine = cl.loadClass("net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch");
            Applet applet = (Applet)Mine.newInstance();
            mcApplet = applet;
            applet.setStub(this);
            applet.setSize(getWidth(), getHeight());
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(applet, "Center");
            applet.init();
            active = true;
            validate();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**НЕ НУЖНО СОВЕТОВАТЬ ИДТИ НА КАКИЕ-ЛИБО ФОРУУМЫ. ТАМ НЕТ НУЖНОЙ ИНФОРМАЦИИ**

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А как выглядит Ваш "Свой лаунчер на java"? Есть какой то код, который не работает, или хотите, чтобы Вам его написали?

Comment: @Духсообщества дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @ProtectchildrenofDonbas2014 дополнил вопрос. Да, есть.

Comment: а теперь давайте код где идет вызов класса `launch`

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко Добавил

Comment: Отлично, он у вас не запустится потому что класс `launch` с модификатором доступ `private` 
Вы можете иным образом вызвать класс `launch`?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко в этом и проблема, что нет. Я искал в интернете решение проблемы - не нашёл

Comment: А есть документация к этой библии?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко Исходя из информации, которую я имею - нет

Comment: а такой запуск пробовали https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch/main? Может быть вы аргументы не передали в метод net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main? Хоть у вас их и нет, но пустой список нужно передавать

Comment: Ну возьмите любой лаунчер по майнкрафту и посмотрите, как они сделали. Сашок, гравит, куча китайских лаунчеров на вкус и цвет...

Comment: @ulxanxv Нет, сейчас попробую.

Comment: И вы не должны пытаться создать класс Launch, его нужно не создавать, а нужно вызывать метод main. Веротянее всего **Mine.newInstance();** вызывает ошибку

Comment: @ulxanxv Я убрал Mine.newInstance(). Теперь нет ошибки, но майнкрафт всё ещё не запускается. Не происходит загрузка, хотя окно появляется.

Comment: Далее я вам уже не подскажу, я ни разу не делал лаунчеры) Просто по конкретно вашей ошибке что-то попробовал подсказать. Возможно туда нужно всё так не пустой список аргументов передавать, а есть какие-то обязательные...

Comment: Как я вижу по той ссылке которую вам скинул, там есть переменная requiredArgs, что означает обязательные параметры

Comment: @ulxanxv Да, хорошо. Благодарю вас за данную помощь

Answer (score 0):

Я хоть и не пишу на java, но интересовался как это можно реализовать, и вот что я знаю на эту тему: Если вы так хотите себе лаунчер - посмотрите в сторону https://launcher.sashok724.net/, но если вы любитель потрепать нервишки - можете попробовать найти в исходниках этого же лаунчера код для запуска майнкрафта (Исходник: https://github.com/new-sashok724/Launcher)

Comment: Я смотрел данный лаунчер.  И исходный код смотрел. Очень не очень пытаться разобраться в чужом коде. Да и если скомпилировать его, а затем запустить - работать не будет. Но я его смотрел, не нашёл того, что искал, к сожалению.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.